# How to get http status code for server down time error in salesforce?

Tags: c#

While update the leads in salesforce, at that time any exception coming from salesforce side. I want to check that exception came for salesforce server down. Also i want how to get the status code for server error when salesforce throws exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the REST API, here are the status codes:

```
200     “OK” success code, for GET or HEAD request.
201     “Created” success code, for POST request.
204     “No Content” success code, for DELETE request.
300     The value returned when an external ID exists in more than one record. The response body contains the list of matching records.
304     The request content has not changed since a specified date and time. The date and time is provided in a If-Modified-Since header. See Get Object Metadata Changes for an example.
400     The request couldn’t be understood, usually because the JSON or XML body contains an error.
401     The session ID or OAuth token used has expired or is invalid. The response body contains the message and errorCode.
403     The request has been refused. Verify that the logged-in user has appropriate permissions.
404     The requested resource couldn’t be found. Check the URI for errors, and verify that there are no sharing issues.
405     The method specified in the Request-Line isn’t allowed for the resource specified in the URI.
415     The entity in the request is in a format that’s not supported by the specified method.
500     An error has occurred within Force.com, so the request couldn’t be completed. Contact salesforce.com Customer Support.
```

[Source](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#CSHID=errorcodes.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Ferrorcodes.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

And [here is a list of Exception Codes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_concepts_core_data_objects.htm) for the core data API calls.

Comment: But i need to get this code when salesforce giving me an exception. Because i want do something when sales force server is down time. Can you please provide me answers?

Comment: When the server is down you'll get Exception Code "SERVER_UNAVAILABLE" or alternatively 500 Status Code if you're using the REST API.

Comment: Can you please give some example code for this?

Comment: Can you please provide code snippets from your end? I can't see how you're approaching this nor which API your using...

Comment: This exception code "SERVER_UNAVAILABLE" comes only when the server down in salesforce. Thanks for your update.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find some additional information how the http status codes from the REST api map to the soap error messages:

```
200 OK
201 CREATED
202 ACCEPTED
204 NO_CONTENT
206 PARTIAL_CONTENT
300 MULTIPLE_CHOICES
301 MOVED_PERMANENTLY
302 FOUND
304 NOT_MODIFIED
400 BAD_REQUEST
401 UNAUTHORIZED
403 FORBIDDEN
404 NOT_FOUND
405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
406 NOT_ACCEPTABLE
409 CONFLICT
410 GONE
412 PRECONDITION_FAILED
413 REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE
414 REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE
415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE
417 EXPECTATION_FAILED
500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
503 SERVER_UNAVAILABLE
```

[source](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_restresponse.htm)